# How to manipulate the keypress that applications recieve?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, vim, autokey

Basically what I want is to create a DIY alternative for autokey because it seems to be so buggy and I can't get it to work on my PC.
What I want to know now is how I can receive a key combination and send something else to an application for example I want vim to receive <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) so I can give different combinations for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. So How can I receive a key combination before vim does and send vim another combination instead of that?